# white css Animation not work in google chrome 34?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

i have a page with a spritesheet animation. This work find, but in GOOGLE CHROME 34.0 i have only the first frame of the .png

my code is:

```
.loadgif{
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  margin: 0% auto;
  background: url('../images/loader/loader.png') left center;
  -webkit-animation: play 1.5s steps(55) infinite;
          animation: play 1.5s steps(55) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
  from { background-position:    0px; }
    to { background-position: -3740px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
  from { background-position:    0px; }
    to { background-position: -3740px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
  from { background-position:    0px; }
    to { background-position: -3740px; }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
  from { background-position:    0px; }
    to { background-position: -3740px; }
}

@keyframes play {
  from { background-position:    0px; }
    to { background-position: -3740px; }
}
```

Exist another way to do this for google chrome 34?

thanks! =)

Comment: Today is ver. 56, and since the browser stats for ver. 34 (2.5 years old) is 0.04%, you and 4 more :), why bother? ... I suggest you update instead

Comment: Ditto. What LGSon said. :D

Comment: Have you tried adding both values (x, y) for `background-position`? ... If you post the actual image you use, so we can see how it looks, we might be able to suggest another way

Comment: Can you provide working example or fiddle?